# Is it possible to add new JPanel to JFrame, after JFrame is loaded?

Tags: java, swing

I'm building a minesweeper game in Java. During the GUI design I came to a problem. Here is my game window.[image]

The grey area supposed to contain the actual mine-field. What I want to happen is that after the player clicks Start Game, I want to load the JPanel that contains the implementation of the mine field. However, it's seems that I can't add any more JPanels after JFrame has loaded, I'm correct? I tried running the addition of the mine field in a different thread (sleep for a few seconds and then add the JPanel), just to see if it's possible, and got no result.

```
public GameWindow(){

        super("Minesweeper");
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        this.gamePanel = new GamePanel(new GridLayout(BOARD_SIZE,BOARD_SIZE,1,1));

        this.timerPanel = new TimerPanel(new BorderLayout(15,15));

        this.timerPanel.initializeFlagLabel(8);

        this.mineField = new Button[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
        int buttonCounter = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i ++){

            for(int j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE; j++){

                mineField[i][j] = new Button();
                mineField[i][j].setName(Integer.toString(buttonCounter++));
                mineField[i][j].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                mineField[i][j].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10,10));
                mineField[i][j].addMouseListener(this);
                gamePanel.add(mineField[i][j]);
            }
        }
        Container container = getContentPane();

        container.add(timerPanel,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        container.add(new MenuPanel(this), BorderLayout.WEST);

        new Thread(new Runnable(){//Here I want to wait for the JFrame to 
                                  //load and then to add the gamePanel.
                 public void run(){
                     try {
                        Thread.sleep(4000);
                        container.add(gamePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

             }
        }); 

        this.setSize(800,640);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }
```

To summarize my question is, is it possible to add new JPanels to JFrame during run-time, and if so how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is, yes. You need to call `revalidate` and `repaint` to trigger a layout and paint pass on the container you've updated.

The longer answer is, probably not the way you're doing it.

Apart from the fact that you never actually `start` the `Thread`, Swing is not thread safe and you shouldn't be updating the UI out side of the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

In you case, a alternative (and safer) solution would be to use a Swing `Timer`.  See [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Comment: Is it a good idea to have menuPanel  implement Observable and the JFrame to implement observer, and when start game is clicked menuPanel will notify the JFrame to load gamePanel?

Comment: Well, what you’re basically describing is a MVC, so yes, it’s not a bad idea

Answer (score 1):

In the action listener for start game, you can add a jpanel to the frame that is precreated. You also may need to `repaint()` or `revalidate()`

Comment: Is it a good idea to have menuPanel implement Observable and the JFrame to implement observer, and when start game is clicked menuPanel will notify the JFrame to load gamePanel by using repaint()?